# Registering a model in Admin page

Tags: python, django

I am trying to register a Model in the Admin page. I have done what exactly i should do to add the Models on the admin page, but it doesn't get displayed. I have tried many solutions discussed over SO to solve this issue but nothing helped.

My code:

```
#settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'MyP',
)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^hoolll/$', 'MyP.views.hello_template'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # i tried this as well---> url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

admin.py

```
from MyP.models import samplemod
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(samplemod)
```

Still nothing gets added on the Admin page. Help

**APP STRUCTURE**

> MyProject
>
> |
>
> |_MyProject
>
> ```
> |___init__.py
>
> |_ settings.py
>
> |_urls.py
> ```
>
> |_MyP
>
> ```
> |__inint__.py
>
> |_Admin.py
>
> |_models.py
>
> |_tests.py
> ```
>
> |_manage.py

Comment: I know but it doesn't. Help

Comment: Did you register ModelAdmin?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac What do you mean register ? Do you mean that i have to add a `AdminModel` in admin.py class?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac i thought it was optional. I have also update my post with the project structure

Comment: rename the admin file to 'admin.py'

Comment: @mislav Yes, that was the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
class SamplemodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   pass
admin.site.register(Samplemod, SamplemodAdmin)
```

and remember
admin.py not Admin.py :)

Comment: It was `Admin.py` that caused this. Thanks loads @Naster and everyone else who posted here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
```

to urls.py

Comment: lol, can't believe I didn't see that. I'm just so used to having it there.

Comment: Well, my urls.py did have it there, but i didn't add it to the post above. It still doesn't work. Help

Comment: Maybe too trivial, but did you try to restart it?

Comment: I have added my Project structure in the post. Yes i restarted the server several times.

Comment: rename Admin.py to admin.py

Comment: and __inint__.py to __init__.py